# How to move desktop icons on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: icons, .desktop, desktop-icons

I can't seem to move any desktop icons on the newest Ubuntu. Whenever I try to move them, they just stay where they are.

How do I move them?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I'm a windows user, so, you know, hold the icon and move it. Nothing happens. Like WTF  is going on in Ubuntu??!?